# what is the best approach to share a single thread between two independent continuous tasks in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 **continuous** jobs called j1 and j2. These two jobs do not have any shared state.
I want to write a program that receives a threadpool of unknown size and share it on both jobs and if the threadpool size is one, the only thread be used for both jobs. in the following code j2 never starts.
I just want an alternative to this so the single thread be shared between both jobs (round robin for example)

```
    @Test
    public void testConcurrency(){
        final Runnable j1 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("a");
                }
            }
        };
        final Runnable j2 = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    System.out.println("b");
                }
            }
        };
        final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(j1);
        executorService.submit(j2);
        executorService.shutdown();

    }
```

I am trying to develop an architecture so that a specific number of threadpools be used in all modules for different tasks. This way I can control the number of threads created and I just need to inject them into modules. and I don't want to face deadlocks because of codes like this. so I was wondering if there is an alternative to code blocks like what I mentioned.
I have considered to force developers to use ScheduledExecutor instead of infinite loops, I just wanted to know if there is something missing that I haven't seen already.

Comment: Pass `j1` and `j2` an `ExecutorService`, have them submit jobs to that. It's irrelevant to the `ExecutorService.submit` method how many threads there are underneath.

Comment: but my jobs are continuous so j1 will never end if it is started first

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I think it would be better to enforce a minThreads=2 constraint. This will be faster than one thread switching contexts.

Comment: Your code looks fine. What's the problem with it? What did you expect and what happens instead?

Comment: it just print a and j2 never executes

Comment: You are using a threadpool of size 1 (`newSingleThreadExecutor`), and since you have programmed your `j1` to loop forever, then of course `j2` never starts. That's how you programmed it! Pass it a threadpool of size 2 or greater.

Comment: I know. I just want an alternative to this so the single thread be shared between both jobs (round robin for example). a clean one of course.

Comment: There is no clean way. This is exactly why Java has threads. If you have an underlying reason why you are asking this, you should mention that. Maybe there is a different solution. Right now, what you want to know doesn't seem to make much sense. Is this just something that you are wondering about?

Comment: setKeepAliveTime can be given to give some time for j1 and then it will terminate and allocate it for the other job. And can implement RejectionHandler but we need to have the thread state saved and resubmitted.. But it complicates..

Comment: I am trying to develop an architecture so that a specific number of threadpools be used in all modules for different tasks. This way I can control the number of threads created and I just need to inject them into modules. and I don't want to face deadlocks because of codes like this. so I was wondering is there an alternative to code blocks like what I mentioned.

Comment: The original motivation for threads was to let programmers to do exactly what you're saying you do _not_ want to do.

When you have two _independent_ computations, (or processes, or tasks or whatever you want to call them,) and you want them both to happen side-by-side; The code that does each of them in its own thread is _much_ easier to read than code that switches back and forth between them in a single thread.  Of course, when the tasks are not fully independent...  That's when multi-threading starts to get tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do the switch between task yourself. For example, you could define an abstract task this way :

```
public abstract class AbstractContinuousTask implements Runnable {

    private long maxDurationInMs = 100;
    private ExecutorService execService;

    public AbstractContinousTask(long maxDurationInMs, ExecutorService execService) {
        this.maxDurationInMs = maxDurationInMs;
        this.execService = execService;
    }

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!Thread.interrupted() && (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < maxDurationInMs)) {
            runInternal();
        }
        execService.submit(this);
    }

    public abstract void runInternal();

}
```

which will call a runInternal method for a given duration (you could instead setup a number of call before returning, etc...).

and then, your task definitions become :

```
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final Runnable j1 = new AbstractContinousTask(100, executorService) {
        @Override
        public void runInternal() {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    };
    final Runnable j2 = new AbstractContinousTask(100, executorService) {
        @Override
        public void runInternal() {
            System.out.println("b");
        }
    };
```

EDIT : 
i've just seen you're last comment about developping a scheduling architecture. Have you looked in scheduling libraries, like Quartz, or Spring (with the @Scheduled annotation) ?

You could also use directly the java Timer api, this way :

```
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("a");
        }
    }, 0, 100);
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("b");
        }
    }, 0, 100);
```

Comment: thank you for the answer @Thierry I think that may be the only way to go

Comment: I have considered to force developers to use ScheduledExecutor instead of infinite loops, I just wanted to know if there is something missing that I haven't  seen already. anyway I'll mark this as an answer. thanks.